# Plotting points on Image using gnuplot.py

Tags: python, gnuplot

Is there a way to plot some points on an image using Gnuplot.py .
I have a text file containing the co-ordinates of the point which i want to plot on an image(as a background.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why is it that you want to use gnuplot.py? I would recommend using the [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/index.htm) (PIL), it has a [ImageDraw](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/imagedraw.htm) module, which allows you to draw on top of images. It would be very straight forward to do this in python.

I appologise if this is not the answer you are looking for, but I have had great results with PIL.

Comment: Ya thats a good option. I actually wanted to get the feeling of tracking a insect in the images i had. I have the co-ordinates of the insect in each frame.
I tried the example given in the ImageDraw module but that just prints rubbish on the screen and does not show the image. Is the example given,correct ??

Comment: The example is correct and does exactly what it says. The only problem is that the example might be a little confusing to you as it outputs the image into `sys.stdout`. To view the image either redirect the output into a file, like: `python imgexample.py > animage.png` or change `im.save(sys.stdout, "PNG")` to `im.save("animage.png`, "PNG")`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. Now it is working fine.
You can also do the same task with the `matplotlib.pyplot` module

Comment: Is it possible to display it on the screen instead of saving it in a file ??

Comment: Sorry got to use the `im.show()` command for displaying on the screen. Thank you.